# Jquery form validation, return user to required field

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

When user tries to submit form without entering data in a required field (class="required"), field is highlighted and given focus.  Except when the field is a select option.  The field is highlighted but user is not returned to the field.  User has to scroll up in this case.

I need the form to scroll up to the highlighted field as it does with the other input types.  Does anyone know the solution for this?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? It scrolls me to the top where the select is in Firefox/Safari/Chrome.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    if (yourSelectFailsValidaton) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('select').focus();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9YwDF/

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with anchor tags. Create an anchor for each required input. Check the required inputs. If you find a blank one, jump to the corresponding anchor.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("jquery", "1");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function jumpToRequired() {
        $("input.required").each(function() {
          var input = $(this);
          if (!input.attr("value")) {
            window.location.hash = input.attr("id") + "_a";
            return;
          }
        });
      }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a name="whatever_a"></a>
    <input type="text" id="whatever" class="required" />
    <button type="button" onclick="jumpToRequired()">Jump to required.</button>
  </body>
</html>
```